# What benefit does useImperativeHandle provide over assigning a forwarded ref in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The example provided in the docs is the following:

```
function FancyInput(props, ref) {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focus: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }));
  return <input ref={inputRef} />;
}
FancyInput = forwardRef(FancyInput);
```

As far as I can see, I can achieve the same thing with

```
function FancyInput(props, ref) {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref) {
      ref.current = {
        focus: () => {
          inputRef.current.focus();
        }
      };
    }
  }, [ref]);
  return <input ref={inputRef} />;
}
FancyInput = forwardRef(FancyInput);
```

The possible explanation that useImperativeHandle is a bit less verbose seems too trivial to me. What’s under the hood? What makes it necessary or better than the useEffect version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TLDR;** It's the same and `useImperativeHandle` just handles all of the `ref` cases and makes sure the passed value is a ref and not just any value.

**Answering your question** It handles for you everything that is need when using refs, so it saves some code.

---

I was looking at the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/95bd7aad7daa80c381faa3215c80b0906ab5ead5/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js) of the hooks and looks like under the hood, `useImperativeHandle` is almost the same as your approach with `useEffect`.

You can take a look at the hooks and see that they have a [HooksDispatcherOnMount](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/95bd7aad7daa80c381faa3215c80b0906ab5ead5/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L1390), [HooksDispatcherOnUpdate](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/95bd7aad7daa80c381faa3215c80b0906ab5ead5/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L1408) and [HooksDispatcherOnRerender](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/95bd7aad7daa80c381faa3215c80b0906ab5ead5/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L1426).

If you look at the functions associated (`fooImperativeHandle` and `fooEffect`) you will see that both call the same function (`fooEffectImpl`).

So apparently, under the hood, it's the same thing, but with when using `useImperativeHandle` you don't need to handle the part of `.current`, it already checks for `null` values, checks if it's a `ref` and sets in returned value in `.current` as you can see [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/95bd7aad7daa80c381faa3215c80b0906ab5ead5/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L1009).

That is what I got from looking at the source code, but if I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the source! Indeed it appears that useImperativeHandle is simply an effect that takes care of the necessary checks, cleanups and accounting for both function and object refs, but instead of using the high level useEffect, it works directly with the low level effect lifecycle functions. I think the biggest reason that it is its own hook could be to ensure backwards compatibility with function refs.